# DatePicker: event when I remove my finger

Tags: android, events, datepicker, motionevent, ontouch

I want to do some actions when I change the date in a `DatePicker`, but this actions I want to be performed only when I remove the finger from the `DatePicker` (last date chosen), so the `OnDateChangedListener()` is not useful for me.

So I thought that an `OnTouchListener()` from the `View` class were that I was looking for:

```
        datePicker.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            Log.i("Evento", String.valueOf(motionEvent.getAction()));
            if  (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                // Actions to be performed
                .....
            }

            return true;
        }
    });
```

But it doesn't work. I watched the logs and the event is detected only just outside of the spinners (but into the `View`). Doesn't work when I touch the spinners itself.

Can someone help me on how to do to launch an event when I remove the finger from the `DatePicker`?